# What are the pros of using Path Finder?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, finder, applescript, pathfinder

What are the pros of using Path Finder, and not Finder?

Could I not get some of the features of Path Finder by adding Applescript scripts to the stock Finder?

Comment: Please rephrase the question so that it is not subjective. Asking "which is better" type questions with no specifics will get them closed quickly.

Comment: You changed the words with your edit, but not the intent. I think you should read the FAQ to get a better understanding of what is an acceptable question. http://superuser.com/faq

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that. I think that the question is not subjective, now.

Comment: that's at least a bit clearer; thanks for editing.  reopening.

Comment: @quack quixote: I apologize; English is not my first language, and sometimes I don't find the words to express a simple concept. Thanks for making my question clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many of the changes in Path Finder cannot be replicated by Applescript scripts because the interface has been fundamentally enhanced. Things like the drop stack, window tabs, dual-pane browsing, integrated terminal, and so forth, cannot just be tacked onto the Finder.

This review should help you discover what Path Finder has to offer:
http://www.macworld.com/reviews/product/413028/review/path_finder_502.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It's now clearer to me what the pro to use Path Finder is.